# Disable, Enable on('click')

Tags: jquery

How can i disable and enable a on click event.

I tried with:

```
$('#web').on('click', function web_function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // execute a bunch of action to preform
});
$('#web').off('click'); // click is succesfully removed
$('#web').on('click'); // doesnt work, i need to redefine the actions to perform
```

Also I tried disabling with:

```
$('#web').unbind('click'); // click is succesfully removed
$('#web').bind('click'); // nok
```

But this also doesnt work...

So, i would like to disable/enable the click event without the need to redefine the actions to perform. Some sort of toggle... (click on/off)

And how do i implement the event to stop propagation?

How can i do this?

Comment: You have to pass in the callback when you are re-binding the event too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass the handler function as the argument whenever you `bind` (or `rebind`).

In your case, you can name the function which you can use to pass it any time you re-bind again.. see below,

```
var myFunc = function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     // execute a bunch of action to preform
}

$('#web').on('click', myFunc); //bind myFunc
$('#web').off('click'); // click is succesfully removed
$('#web').on('click', myFunc); //rebind again
```

Comment: I edit my question a little bit... i overlooked the event i'm using... can you show me how to implement this in your example?

Comment: can you just approve my edit? if its correct? then your answer meets my question :-)

Comment: @Nomistake I didn't reject it.. http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/457236  however updated it.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

first disable the element using `prop()` method of jQuery, i.e.

```
$("selector").prop("disabled",true);
```

and when you want to enable click the just do it by using

```
$("selector").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks.

Comment: if I use attr instead of prop, will it attach previously attached onclick event as well?

Comment: as per official docs "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method." using attr() is not a standard way for setting dom properties.